# DotNetOpenAuth and OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I installed the 4.0 beta from NuGet using the following command:

> PM > Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth -Pre

I also download the source from  https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/commit/v4.0.0.12030-Beta1 .

I'm trying to build a client that will login to [salesforce.com](http://www.salesforce.com) using the *Salesforce.net REST API*

I need to use `OAuth2`. While the beta source code has a `DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2` namespace, the binary package from NuGet doesn't have that namespace available.

Is `OAuth2` supported in the 4.0 beta?  If not what version do I need to download in order to use `OAuth2`?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Because OAuth 2 isn't a finalized spec, DNOA 4.0 will not be including an OAuth 2 implementation, so it's not in the beta.  To get OAuth2 preview support, you need to download a [different SKU of DNOA](https://nuget.org/packages/DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client.UI).

```
Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client.UI -Pre
```